# how to return enumerate in method

Tags: java

Product.java

```
public interface Product {
    /**
     * use this interface for creating your own enumerate of products
     */
    public static interface Category {
        enum MyCategory {vegetable, fruit, chocolate};   // i create my own enumerate

    }

}
```

in my MyProduct.java i need implement getCategory() method

```
public class MyProduct implements Product {

    @Override
    public Category getCategory() {
     // ???
    }

}
```

but i don't know how to access enumerate from interface Category and still returning variable of Category. Con you help me please. 
Sorry for bad description of my problem, but I hope you understand what I need :)

Comment: All I can say is that this design is a monstrosity. Why did you embed `MyCategory` not one, but two levels deep?

Comment: Enum can implement interface.

Comment: Actually, I think what the OP might want is for every implementation of `Category` to be able to return a different `enum`. Which is impossible, `enum`s are types and thus can't be interface members.

Answer (score 4):

The full name of the enum would be `Product.Category.MyCategory` (prefixed by the package name if any). Within `Product`, you can write that as just `Category.MyCategory`.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this if the `enum` isn't `static`.

Comment: @millimoose: You can (just tried, to be sure -- my fu in this area isn't as strong as it could be, as I don't do that kind of nesting, so I figured I should check).

Comment: Ah. It seems that Java makes inner `enum`s implicitly `static`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to return enum as Interface.
Enums can implement Interface so `MyCategory` can implement `Category`

```
public interface Product {
    /**
     * use this interface for creating your own enumerate of products
     */
    public static interface Category {
        enum MyCategory implements Category {
            vegetable, fruit, chocolate
        }; // i create my own enumerate

    }
    Category getCategory();
}
```

So your product class can do

```
public class MyProduct implements Product {
    @Override
    public Category getCategory() {
        return Product.Category.MyCategory.chocolate;
    }
}
```